# converting string to int in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to convert a string I read in from a file to an int value so I can store it in an integer variable. This is what my code looks like:

```
ifstream sin;  
sin.open("movie_output.txt");  
string line;  
getline(sin,line);  
myMovie.setYear(atoi(line));
```

Over here, setYear is a mutator in the Movie class (myMovie is an object of Movie class) that looks like this:

```
void Movie::setYear(unsigned int year)  
{  
    year_ = year;  
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
error C2664: 'atoi' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'  
1> No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Comment: It's like one of those recurring newsgroup posts. We should just sync these with recurring answer posts and everyone will be happy.

Comment: ... and then add that same usual comment response for those who suggest using `atoi()`, and then seriously all will be swell.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: If you can find a duplicate, feel free to mark as such...

Comment: @Billy 1243428 2023519 1766150 893670 1883056 2393873 200090 1878001 1141741 1817992 504635 64782 2073054 225362 194465 1496536 2066184 and this isn't an exhaustive list, mind you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myMovie.setYear(atoi(line.c_str()));`

Comment: ah, that works. thanks a ton. also, if you dont mind, could you please explain why the .c_str() is required?

Comment: @xbonez: Because atoi does not work on strings. It works on const char *s. atoi is a relic from the C standard. To make a string into a const char *, you call the c_str member.

Comment: C++ has 2 ways of storing strings - the first way is carried over from C, which is char*, basically an array (or pointer to an array) of chars, and the second way is the new std::string. However, they aren't equivalent and many functions expecting char*s (like the atoi function which was carried over from C) can't process std::string inputs. Thus in some cases you may need to get the C style string (c_str()) from the std::string in order to make it work.

Comment: this uses stdlib.h . is there a way to do it without it?

Answer (score 10):

Rather than using `std::getline(std::string&, std::istream&)`, why not just use the stream extraction operator on the file?

```
ifstream sin;
sin.open("movie_output.txt");
unsigned int year = 0;
sin >> year;
myMovie.setYear(year);
```

Comment: For error handling, when there was no number in the file, `sin.fail()` is true after the year extraction.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

Use the lexical_cast:

```
int value = boost::lexical_cast<int>(line);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do `atoi(line.c_str())`

Another approach, using C++ streams, is:

```
stringstream ss(line);
unsigned int year;
ss >> year;
```

Comment: stream is definitely better option

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix is to use line.c_str() which provides a const char* for atoi().

A better solution (if available) may be to use boost::lexical_cast(line). This is a neater version of the C++ism of pushing things into and out of a std::stringstream which has all the type conversions you are likely to need.