# How to change a string to a int number in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting string to int in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634558/converting-string-to-int-in-c)

I have tried include `stdlib.h` but it doesn't work.

Comment: May be below link will help you. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: What have you actually tried in code?

Answer (score 2):

in c++98 you can do

```
std::string str("1234");
int i;
std::stringstream ss(str);
ss >> i;
```

in c++11 you should do:

```
std::string str("1234");
int i=std::stoi(str);
```

Answer (score -1):

A more C++-way of doing this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// Converts a string to anything.
template<typename T>
T to(const std::string& s)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    T ret;
    ss >> ret;
    return ret;
}

// And with a default value for not-convertible strings:
template<typename T>
T to(const std::string& s, T default_)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    ss >> default_;
    return default_;
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
int i = to<int>("123");
assert(i == 123);
int j = to<int>("Not an integer", 123);
assert(j == 123);
```

And extend it to support arbitrary types of yours:

```
struct Vec3 {float x, y, z;};

template<class T>
T& operator>>(T& f, Vec3& v) {
    f >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z;
    return f;
}

// Somewhere else:
Vec3 v = to<Vec3>("1.0 2.0 3.0");
```